# How to find the local timezone offset in Rust?

Tags: rust

How to find the local timezone offset in Rust? is there an easy way to find it without using a crate like Chronos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`chrono::offset::Local`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Local.html) uses "the standard `time` crate", so you can use that instead of `chrono` if you want.

[`UtcOffset::try_current_local_offset()`](https://docs.rs/time/0.2.25/time/struct.UtcOffset.html#method.try_current_local_offset) should do what you need. Or `try_local_offset_at()` if you need the offset as it is, was or will be at a particular moment.

If you want something from `std` (or even `core`), I don't think it exists. At least not in a platform-independent way.